# Fontspec: Copy of sans-serif font with different WordSpace

Tags: spacing, luatex, fontspec

I'm trying to define a copy of my default sans-serif font, but with a different inter word spacing.
However, simply *defining* this font family changes `\sffamily`'s inter word spacing if both families use the same scaling factor.

Minimal Working Example:

```
% !TeX program = lualatex
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{fontspec}

\setsansfont{texgyreheroscn}[
    Ligatures=TeX,
    Scale=MatchUppercase
]

\newfontfamily{\spacedsffamily}{texgyreheroscn}[
    Ligatures=TeX,
% commenting the following line changes word spacing to the expected value:
    Scale=MatchUppercase,
    WordSpace=2
]

\begin{document}

\textsf{This is a test to show word spacing}

\end{document}
```

Although `\spacedsffamily` is not used in the document, the inter word space I'm observing matches `WordSpace=2`. If I comment the line `Scale=MatchUppercase` or put a different scaling factor (that doesn't match `\sffamily`'s), the observed inter word space changes.

To me, this looks as if `WordSpace` is applied globally to all fonts with same filename and scaling factor.

Is there an explanation for this behavior or even a workaround? (except the obvious: making a copy of the otf file, but this creates a second embedded font subset in the resulting pdf)

Comment: you need two fonts (for the same reason that you can't set word space in \addfontfeatures). You could e.g. add a small scale factor `Scale=1.001`.

Comment: I think I might have found a (possibly hacky) workaround: Adding `RawFeature=+doesnotexist` seems to work, both families now have equal Scale, but different WordSpace values. (Introducing a custom font feature instead, e.g. replacing any char using a substitution, seems to also work)....